# How to move the blue box from the right outer side of the parent component to the left outer side

Tags: flutter

[How to move the blue box from the right outer side of the parent component to the left outer side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm5NC.png)，Blue box width is not fixed。

Comment: please be more specific with your question

Answer (score 0):

The order widget appear on the screen is dictate by the order they are listed in the `Row` or other widget they are wrapped in. Widgets at the top will be on the left and widgets on the bottom will be on the right.

```
Row(
        children: [
          Container(color: Colors.red),//left widget
          Container(color: Colors.blue),//right widget
        ],
      ),
```

This is a very simplified explanation as your application grows obviously things become more complex but this principle remains true.